# Why is there a small ッ in 完ッ全?

Tags: words, colloquial-language

I found [this sentence](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%83%83%E5%85%A8%20%23sentences) on Jisho.org recently:

> どーすんの、このお店{みせ}！完{かん}ッ全{ぜん}に閑古鳥{かんこどり}が鳴{な}いちゃってるじゃない。
>   What happened to this place?! It's completely dead!

I am baffled as to why there is a small ッ in the middle of 完全. The furigana provided ignores it, and I would be surprised if it were a typo because it is in the middle of a word with kanji. I've never seen anything like this before.

Is the small ッ supposed to affect the pronunciation of the word? Why is it there?

Comment: I've never seen this in writing either, but I figure it indicates a mid-word pause for emphasis, which is something you often hear in speech - and the sentence is clearly colloquial, given the どーすんの at the beginning. (Sort of like やはり→やっぱり, though of course やっぱり is lexicalized while かんっぜん isn't.)

Comment: By the way, I think the idiom is usually [閑古鳥が鳴く](http://zokugo-dict.com/06ka/kankodori.htm), not 閑古鳥が鳴る.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When っ is placed in the middle of a word, it's showing an elongation/stress for emphasis.

For starters, this appears in many common words not written in kanji, notably:

> すっごい (even すっげー), from 凄{すご}い
>
> やっぱり, from やはり

In a lot of colloquial Japanese, っ serves as a small hiccup (in reality a geminated consonant, or sometimes a glottal stop), and is used very commonly for emphasis. Perhaps you've heard some of the following:

> 全{ぜん}ッ然{ぜん}わかんない！
>
> I don't understand AT ALL. (emphasis that you understand 0% of what's being said)
>
> 絶{ぜっ}ッ対{たい}ダメ！
>
> NO WAY! (emphasis that it's totally out of the question)

In your example, we see the same thing as above -- ッ is added between the kanji (almost as an okurigana) showing that the speaker is stretching out (and slightly straining) the ん sound in かんぜん, which gives the effect of emphasizing that it really is 完全に.

Showing where the emphasis lies:

> どーすんの、このお店{みせ}！完{かん}ッ全{ぜん}に閑古鳥{かんこどり}が鳴{な}いちゃってるじゃない。
>
> What happened to this place?! It's TOTALLY dead!

It's hard to explain the っ, but I found a good example that came to mind. In https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6A_pU1Tdhjo#t=2m15s, Hatoko (the pink haired girl) says "全ッ然わかんない" right after where I set the timestamp. Hopefully it gives a clear idea of what the ッ sounds like here, and in 完ッ全.

Comment: やっぱり might be a slightly different phenomenon - the lengthening makes it fit the ◯っ◯り adverb pattern seen in things like こっそり or はっきり.